# What is the purpose of AuthenticationManagerBuilder in Oauth2 resource server

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

So I have this application that only allow access to its resource when a valid oauth token is provided.  I already have an @EnableResourceServer class that handles role based access to different endpoints.  But what is the purpose of the block of code below?  My app would not start unless I put in this generic block with some generic user name/password.  The user/role/password here has no bearing on accessing the resource whatsoever.  As long as the role in the oauth token matches the role specified in the @EnableResourcesServer, the caller will get proper response back from the app.

```
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
...
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception 
    {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication() // creating user in memory
                .withUser("user")
                .password("password").roles("USER")
                .and().withUser("admin")
                .password("password").authorities("ROLE_ADMIN");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, it was because I separated the access of resources in 2 classes, an @EnableResourceServer and an @EnableWebsecurity.  The issue is resolved after removing the @EnableWebSecurity class and moving all access control to @EnableResourceServer.